# How to pass value from text view to variable for other activities in Android?

Tags: android

I am having a problem assigning a Text-view result [from database] to a new variable.
Text-view retrieve data from database no issue.

Now issue is i need to link the value "4" in the Text-view to a new variable. Then use button function for my next activity.

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView name1;
TextView rating1;
TextView sourse1;
Button Btngetdata;
int ratingvalue;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://lawrencetucksoon.netau.net/json_get_data.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_APPINFO = "appinfo";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
//private static final String TAG_UPDATE_PATCH = "update patch";
//private static final String TAG_PUBLISH_YEAR = "publish year";
private static final String TAG_RATING = "rating";
private static final String TAG_SOURSE = "sourse";

JSONArray app = null;

/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    rating1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);
    sourse1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sourse);
    Btngetdata=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println(ratingvalue);
        }
    });
}

public void selectapp (View view)
{
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.radio_365:
            if (checked)
            {
                new JSONParse().execute();
                if((Integer.parseInt(rating1.getText().toString()) ) <=3)
                {
                    ratingvalue =0;
                }
                else
                  {
                   ratingvalue = 1;
                  }
            }
           break;
        case R.id.radio_candy: //if (R.id.rating > 3){
            // ratingvalue = 0;
            if (checked)
           {
               new JSONParse1().execute();

               }
               // else
             //  {
              //     ratingvalue = 1;
              // }

           // }
            break;
       case R.id.radio_FB:
           if (checked)
            {
                new JSONParse().execute();

           }
            break;
        case R.id.radio_summoner:
            if (checked)
            {
                new JSONParse1().execute();

            }

            break;
    }

}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        rating1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);
        sourse1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sourse);

        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... args) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        //  Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        //super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
       // if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array
            app = json.getJSONArray(TAG_APPINFO);
            JSONObject c = app.getJSONObject(0);

            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String rating = c.getString(TAG_RATING);
            String sourse = c.getString(TAG_SOURSE);

            //Set JSON Data in TextView
            name1.setText(name);
            rating1.setText(rating);
            sourse1.setText(sourse);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

private class JSONParse1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {


    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        rating1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);
        sourse1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sourse);

        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... args) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        //  Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        //super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        // if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array
            app = json.getJSONArray(TAG_APPINFO);
            JSONObject c = app.getJSONObject(1);

            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String rating = c.getString(TAG_RATING);
            String sourse = c.getString(TAG_SOURSE);

            //Set JSON Data in TextView
            name1.setText(name);
            rating1.setText(rating);
            sourse1.setText(sourse);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't get what you're trying to say!

Comment: inside radio button i have retrieve data from database n paste it to textview....Now i want to paste the textview result to a variable so i can use for next activity as calculation part...

Answer (score 0):

In first activity you need to pass argument to intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("param", myTextView.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in second activity's onCreate

```
Intent intent = getIntent()
String value = intent.getStringExtra("param", null);
```

Comment: but i want to use such value continue for calculation part...so String value is the variable now??   because i still need to do further if else function...your method i saw on youtube..it just display the value on the new intent pages...

Comment: bro, i think i start to understand what you trying to said....paste the value to intent....then continue from the 2nd activity there....thanks will try this method later...

Comment: if you want to convert string value to int just add to my answer 'int intValue = Integer.parseInt(value);'

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways. The first one is to declare a **static** variable and make it **public**. Then u can access the variable from other activity. For example if you have the `TextView` on activity **A** and want to access the value from activity `B`. In you can declare the variable as

```
public static String someVariable;
```

then set the value for the variable whereever you want. After that when activity **B** is launched access the variable where required. Eg.

```
...
String variable=A.someVariable;
...
```

although this method is simple it is not considered to be a good option. The good option is to send the value in intents. For the intents see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)